# SSIS package FLAT File load to SQL table and transform data to truncate trialing spaces, convert string to datetime

Tags: ssis

I have a Flat file with a fixed width of size 6 GB.
I need to load this flat file to SQL table before loading I need to validate and transform data.

Validation - Tuncate empty spaces

Transformation - convert string (20210228) to datatime (2021-02-28 00:00:00)

These are my thoughts

1. To load data, I have used the Dataflow task with Flat file Source, OLED Data source (with a table or view Fast load option) it took 3 min to load ( which is not of concern)
2. Run Stored procedure to truncate the empty spaces, convert DateTime (took around 1 hour)

My concern is with the second step, I need to update around 50 Million rows and the stored procedure took a lot of time to finish.

I am looking for ways to bring down the data transformation time.

Comment: update around 50 Million rows ? For which need exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add those two data transformations to your SSIS Data Flow and upload the converted dates and trimmed values instead of the original file.  You can do this with the Derived Column transformation, with lots more details available [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-derived-columns-with-multiple-expressions-vs-multiple-transformations/) if you can't work it out.

Because the Derived Column transformation is not a blocking transform (i.e. it doesn't need to work on more than one row of data at a time) you shouldn't really have any performance issues.